# Using built-in List functions to check membership across two lists in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, higher-order-functions

I am wondering if there is a way to solve the following problem using `List.filter`, `List.for_all`, and `List.exists`.

I have a list of user defined type `car` that looks like:

```
car1 = Car (1, 2, 3, [Red; Blue])
car2 = Car (3, 2, 4, [Purple; Black; Gold; Blue])
car3 = Car (4, 3, 1, [Gold; Purple])
```

Where the list is passed as an argument containing cars like `[car1; car2; car3]`

And then I have another list of colours `[Blue, Black]`

The goal is to return the back the list of cars that don't have these colours. So following the example above, the function should return:

```
[car1; car3]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Sorry I should've mentioned, this is a homework problem however I can't seem to wrap my head around functional programming.

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful problem description. Please describe exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, I have edited to include my updated code. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: You haven't said what the actual errors or test cases are. You also haven't provided the type definitions.

Comment: Beware `!=`. You probably want `<>`. To see why, test `"hello" != "hello"` in the OCaml toplevel.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a homework problem, so I'll just make some observations.

You can solve the problem with `List.filter` if you can write a function to tell whether a given car is one of the ones that should be in the output list. In other words you need a function like this:

```
let doesnt_have_color colors car =
    match car with
    | Car (_, _, _ carcolors) -> true or false
```

It's not completely clear from your description of the problem, but I assume the function should return true if there are no colors in common between `colors` and `carcolors`.

Now you have the problem of telling whether there are any elements in common between two lists. There are elements in common between lists a and b if any of the elements of a (i.e., a test using `List.exists`) is an element of b (another test using `Lists.exists` or, more idiomatically, `List.mem`).

Comment: Yes it is a homework problem. I have updated the question to include my code so far. It doesn't work but I am really stuck and have been at it for a while now. Any further help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

*A* way of looking at this would be to get the intersection of two lists using `List.filter` and `List.mem`.

```
let intersect a b =
  List.(
    filter (fun x -> mem x b) a
  )
```

```
utop # intersect [1;2;3;4; 6] [1;4;5;6];;
- : int list = [1; 4; 6]
```

Of course, you don't actually need to find all of the items in the first list that *exist* in the second. You just need to find out if there *exist* any overlapping items.

---

> ```
> let getCar cars =
>   match cars with
>   |x::xs -> x
> ;;
> ```

A few notes on this:

- A `match` with only one clause is usually better written as either a let bindings, or using the function argument to destructure the data.
- The pattern-matching here is not exhaustive. It does not handle an empty list.
- `xs` does not need to be bound to a name, as you have not used it.
- You have just reimplemented `List.hd`.

> ```
> let getColors car =
>   match car with
>   | Car(_,_,_,colors) -> colors
> ;;
> ```

This can readily be written (OCaml style prefers `_` rather than "camel case"):

```
let get_colors (Car (_, _, _, colors)) = colors
```

> ```
> let banned_free (not_wanted : colours list) (cars : car list) =
>   let car = getColors(getCar(cars)) in
>   List.filter (function Car (_,_,_,colors) ->
>       List.for_all (fun col ->
>           List.for_all ((!=) col) colors) car )
> ;;
> ```

There are a number of issues here, but I don't believe I can assist with this without more details and clarity.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have to use all three of List.exists, List.for_all, and List.filter. I just updated the question to include my new code. Unfortunately, this is still failing all test cases. If you are able to provide any further feedback that would be appreciated!